# bash reading text in from a log file with colours, strip colour

Tags: bash, file

I want to read a password in from an installation log file and remove the initial text from the line so I am just left with the password itself, so I can use it in a script variable. I can do this okay, however when it reads the line in, its bringing the colour with it (The line is highlighted green in the log file) I want to strip the colours from the line but I dont know how. my code snippet for reading in the line is just:

```
grep -h "MySQL root password" /root/logs/installer.log |
while read mysqlpass ; do
mysqlpass="${mysqlpass//MySQL root password: }"
printf "$mysqlpass\n"
done
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed a sample of your log file (change the password!), so we can see exactly what you mean about the colours being included.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
mysqlpass="${mysqlpass//MySQL root password: }"
mysqlpass=$( echo "$mysqlpass" | sed -e $'s#\033\[[;0-9]*m##g' )
```

Take a look at the `ansi_colours.sh` script on [this page](https://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/terminal_colours/) for better understanding of the colors.